# How to add background image in CocosSharp?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, game-development, cocossharp

I have used this code to add background image in CCLayer but it's not working:

```
public class GameLayer : CCLayerColor
{
    private CCSprite background; 
    public GameLayer() : base(CCColor4B.Transparent)
    {       
        background = new CCSprite("cbg")
        {
            AnchorPoint = new CCPoint(0, 0),
            IsAntialiased = true,
            Position = new CCPoint(0, 0),

        };
        this.AddChild(background);
    }
}
```

My problem is image is displaying but not of screen size as background image, its just displaying at the bottom-left corner of the screen.

**EDIT:**
**Solved:**
To solve this problem I have added Contnetsize to my image same as screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use to display a background :

```
var sprite = new CCSprite("bg.jpg");
sprite.AnchorPoint = new CCPoint(0, 0);
sprite.IsAntialiased = false;
layer.AddChild(sprite);
```

almost the same code, but CocosSharp has strange behaviours sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try this out and let you know.

Comment: This didn't solved the problem, I added content size to add background image according to screen size.